# Объявление строки

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Надо объявить строку

```
NSString *str=@" "Всем привет!" ";
```

Проге не нравится то, что в кавычках кавычки стоят. А мне надо, чтобы когда эта переменная объявляла, текст был именно в кавычках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*str=@" \"Всем привет!\" "
```

Не?

Comment: Да,супер!Спасибо!

Comment: Нельзя просто так взять и вставить виджет погоды в каменты

Comment: Да че за фигню ты сюда постишь постоянно? =)

Comment: @knes, это его личный блог :)

Comment: Супер. А то что оно бампается постоянно - это так, фигня? =) От этого так просто не отпишешься, в отличие от уведомлений.

Comment: http://arm1.ru/blog/ispolzovanie-uinavigationcontroller-vmeste-s-uitabbarcontroller